# ObjC: how to add escape character so "hello" becomes \"hello\"?

Tags: iphone, escaping

Currently I am using stringByReplacingOccuranceOfString... to replace " with \", but is there any smarter way?

Thanks!

Comment: I dont understand the issue, can you further explain.
Do you want the string to be '\"hello\"'? or '"hello"'

Comment: the original string is "hello" (includes the "), now I want the string to be \"hello\" (includes slash and ")

Comment: your current method seems to be the best then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this,

```
  NSString *str = @"hello";
  NSString *escape = @"\\\””;  // this adds ***//*** & then ***/"*** 
  NSString *newStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", escape, str, escape];
  NSLog(@"%@", newStr);
```